# Google Maps API, how to limit number of results?

Tags: php, google-maps

I'm working for a town hall website. They have a database containing +-13,000 apartments.

I do an engine that retrieves x apartments and put them on the map with their address, zip code etc...

Is there a way to limit number of response with the API ?

For example, if we try to put more than 100 apartments ont the map, we have an error message.

I need to do that for save resources on my server, and not to exceed the limit imposed by the Google Maps API (free version).

If there isn't solution, i can do that on my side, but it's not very easy for me now.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

First of all - preparations:

Create index for appartments: this will be used later to limit number of appartments on zoom-level.
Save to DB coordinates for all appartments (in future it's better to store them, when you add it to DB, so there is no need to index all 13k+ at same moment)

After this follow simple logic: show only appartments in viewport of the map and only with zoomLevel equal to index in DB (that we create manualy, or it may be random)